# Fill Array with Data from MongoDB in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got a problem referencing the asynchronous behaviour of Node.JS:

I'm trying to fill an Array with Data from a Mongo Database and send it to a page. Of course the Array is empty and i would like to know how it could be resolved. I googled already about keeping control flow, but not really found an example, how to handle nested MongoDB querys or something like this:

```
Session.find({$or:[{owner:useremail},{users:{$in:[useremail]}}]},function(err,sessions){

        if(sessions){

            var lastSessionNotes=[];
            var numCompletedCalls = 0;

            for(var i=0;i<sessions.length;i++){


                Notes.find({sessionId:sessions[i].uuid}).sort({creation:-1}).limit(1).exec(function(err,note){

                    var lastnotedate;
                    var lastNoteObject={};

                    if(typeof note[0]!='undefined'){

                        console.log(note);
                        lastnotedate=note[0].creation;

                        lastNoteObject={sessionID:note[0].sessionId,lastNote:lastnotedate};
                        lastSessionNotes.push(lastNoteObject);
                        numCompletedCalls=numCompletedCalls+1;

                    }

                });

            }


            console.log(lastSessionNotes.length);
            res.render('home',{username:req.session.user, sessions:sessions, lastSessionNotes:lastSessionNotes});


        }
    });
```

Many thanks in advance

Edit:

I got it working now, but now I got the problem, that i have one Object always twice in my Array which should not be. The Notes.find-Query goes through the Notes, sorts them by Date and returns the latest one.

I really don't get it, course if I return sessons[i], there is no Array returned twice.

Here The Code:

```
Session.find({$or:[{owner:useremail},{users:{$in:[useremail]}}]},function(err,sessions){

                if(sessions){

                    var lastSessionNotes=[];

                    var numCompletedCalls = 0;


                    for(var i=0;i<sessions.length;i++){

                        console.log(sessions[i]);
                        Notes.find({sessionId:sessions[i].uuid}).sort({creation:-1}).limit(1).exec(function(err,note){

                            var lastnotedate;
                            var lastnotesessioniD;
                            var lastNoteObject={};

                            if(typeof note[0]=='undefined'){

                                lastnotedate="Nothing";
                                //console.log(sessions[numCompletedCalls]);
                                lastnotesessioniD=sessions[numCompletedCalls].uuid;


                            }else{

                                lastnotedate=note[0].creation;
                                lastnotesessioniD=note[0].sessionId;

                            }

                            lastNoteObject={sessionID:lastnotesessioniD,lastNote:lastnotedate};
                            lastSessionNotes.push(lastNoteObject);

                            numCompletedCalls=numCompletedCalls+1;
                            console.log(numCompletedCalls+"  "+sessions.length);

                            if (numCompletedCalls == sessions.length) {
                                console.log(lastSessionNotes);
                                res.render('home',{username:req.session.user, sessions:sessions, lastSessionNotes:lastSessionNotes});
                            }

                        });

                    }


                }

            });
```

Output:

```
[ { sessionID: 'Klz8g1', lastNote: 'Nothing' },
{ sessionID: 'Klz8g1', lastNote: 1399485395975 },
{ sessionID: 'Pcfu5Z', lastNote: 1399477346484 },
{ sessionID: 'D241jz', lastNote: 1399485746096 },
{ sessionID: 'EvgXE4', lastNote: 'Nothing' },
{ sessionID: '348oay', lastNote: 1399486524033 },
{ sessionID: 'qkFqPh', lastNote: 'Nothing' },
{ sessionID: 'UeY4c9', lastNote: 'Nothing' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close as you're keeping track of the number of completed `Notes.find` operations in `numCompletedCalls`, but you're not doing anything with it.  You need to move the `res.render` call inside the callback and call it when `numCompletedCalls` shows that all operations have completed.

```
Session.find({$or:[{owner:useremail},{users:{$in:[useremail]}}]},function(err,sessions){
    if(sessions){
        var lastSessionNotes=[];
        var numCompletedCalls = 0;

        for(var i=0;i<sessions.length;i++){
            Notes.find({sessionId:sessions[i].uuid}).sort({creation:-1}).limit(1).exec(function(err,note){
                var lastnotedate;
                var lastNoteObject={};

                if(typeof note[0]!='undefined'){
                    console.log(note);
                    lastnotedate=note[0].creation;

                    lastNoteObject={sessionID:note[0].sessionId,lastNote:lastnotedate};
                    lastSessionNotes.push(lastNoteObject);
                }

                numCompletedCalls=numCompletedCalls+1;                    
                if (numCompletedCalls === sessions.length) {
                    console.log(lastSessionNotes.length);
                    res.render('home',{username:req.session.user, sessions:sessions, lastSessionNotes:lastSessionNotes});
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx for the reply first of all :)
I tried this, but it ends in a loop.

Comment: @user3613549 See updated code.  I don't have a way to try this, but it should work now.

Comment: I got it partially working now, but have some trouble, because in the filled Array there is always one Entry twice, which should not be. I edited my post above. I would be pleased if you could take a look at it :)